# django rest framework return a custom object

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models (Like and News). I am using django-rest-framework to make a web api out of it.

Models:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class News(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...
    likes = GenericRelation(Like)
```

Serializers for the two model:

```
class LikeObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, User):
            return 'User: ' + value.username
        elif isinstance(value, News):
            return 'News: ' + value.title
        ...
        raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')

class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    content_object = LikeObjectRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        field = ('user', 'content_object', 'pub_date')

class NewsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    likes = LikeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'body', 'article_image', 'pub_date', 'likes')
```

view:

```
class NewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = News.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer
```

With this I get the json objects. But for the News object, I only want the number of likes for a news item and check whether `request.user` is present in that item's likes list. Instead I am getting back all the user (and the users info) and likes content-object, again the users, etc.

If I make a custom field for the Like to use in the NewsSerializer, I can get the number of likes. But I can't check if the request.user is in the Likes list.

```
class LikeRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.count()
```

What do I do to get only the number of likes for a News object. Also check if the `request.user` is in that likes list and maybe add a boolean of `user_in_likes:True` or False for each News object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) instead of custom field. This way you can access `request` through `self.context['request']` in serializer method, and do all calculations of your `Like` model.